# Infinite summation with limit of quotient of consecutive coefficiants known

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

Let us say that there is an operation $f(x)$ such that $\lim({x\to ∞})\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ is $l$. A summation is given below.
$$\sum_{k=0}^∞ f(k)n^k$$

Is there any way to write the above infinite summation using $l$, as the sum of an infinite summation that we can easily compute through basic telescoping and a polynomial with a finite degree? If so, then how?

Even if it is not possible, please do help on how to simplify the above summation. All answers are wlcome. Thank you.

Comment: I assume $n < 1$?

Comment: Yes. You can assume that $n<1$

Comment: Computing it won't be possible, since you could just change the a finite amount of values of $f(n)$ and the limit $l$ will remain unchanged but the sum can alter drastically. But it isn't hard to prove that it converges if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: No. I'm not trying to prove its convergence

Comment: Then what are you trying to do? Because it's hard to answer your question (if not impossible) without putting more restrictions on $f$.